# Recursive method to print all the permutations of an array

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, recursion, permutation

I built a recursive method that is supposed to print all the permutations of an array, but it's only printing the first option.

This is the code:

```java
public static void printPermutation(int[] nums, int index, int[] print_arr) {
    if (index == nums.length) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(print_arr));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        if (nums[i] > 0) {
            print_arr[index] = nums[i];
            nums[i] = -1;
            printPermutation(nums, index + 1, print_arr);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi. can you please correct the word resvuisive to recursive and give us an example to understand what you want to do? thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your array is printed depending on the length of the `nums` input. Please include how you execute this function.

Answer (score 0):

After "removing" a number from nums by setting it to -1, you need to add it back so that the next iteration of the loop starts with the same state. Otherwise you end up filling `nums` with -1. With this change I got all the permutations of 1,2,3 correctly:

```java
if (nums[i] > 0) {
    print_arr[index] = nums[i];
    nums[i] = -1;
    printPermutation(nums, index + 1, print_arr);
    // reset back to initial state
    nums[i] = print_arr[index];
}
```